# spring data - query left join with ElementCollection

Tags: java, sql, spring, join, spring-data-jpa

I have a entity ConventionEntity with network object and list of Object activityTypes

I want to search conventions with multiple criteria, i used spring data so i used query for search

With the below query i have this error

> org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection
>   element: categoryPerimeter [SELECT c FROM
>   com.softilys.entities.ConventionEntity c JOIN c.activityTypes act
>   WHERE act.categoryPerimeter = :perimeter AND c.network.networkName IN
>   (:networkNames) AND c.title = :title ]

```
@Entity
public class ConventionEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String title;

private Network network;

@ElementCollection
private Set<ActivityType> activityTypes;

}

public class Network implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String networkName;
}

public class ActivityType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String categoryPerimeter;
}


@Repository
public interface ConventionRepository extends JpaRepository<ConventionEntity, String> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM ConventionEntity c "
            + "LEFT JOIN c.activityTypes act "
            + "WHERE act.categoryPerimeter = :perimeter "
            + "AND c.network.networkName IN (:networkNames) "
            + "AND c.title = :title ")
    List<ConventionEntity> searchConventions(@Param("title") String title, @Param("perimeter") String perimeter ,
            @Param("networkNames") List<String> networkNames);

}
```

Comment: from t1 join t2 ON ...

Comment: @jarlh the same problem : SELECT c FROM ConventionEntity c JOIN c.activityTypes act ON act.categoryPerimeter = :perimeter WHERE c.title = :title